# Will changing a favicon daily destroy SEO or raise any concerns with search engines?

Tags: seo, images, favicon, change-frequency

I've been reading this question on StackOverflow [Can I change a favicon daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585932/can-i-change-a-favicon-daily), but I'd like to know if changing the favicon daily mess up any SEO or raise any concerns with search engines?

I am using Ubuntu's Apache.

Comment: Don't browsers tend to heavily cache favicons because they rarely change - therefore changing them daily probably won't be noticed by most people.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585932/can-i-change-a-favicon-daily I should be able to move the favicons outside the root directory to bypass the cache.

Answer (score 1):

No, favicon is mostly affecting user experience and the brand awareness it wont have any affect on SEO.

Read more about favicons:
https://www.woorank.com/en/blog/the-importance-of-favicons-for-seo